# distribute python package without publishing it in PyPi

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have a github repository with this structure:

```
myrepo/
|-- myrepo/
| |-- myproject.py
| |
| |-- test/
|   |--- test_myproject.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- requirements.txt
|-- README.md
|-- LICENSE.md
```

Since this project is only to be shared with a few colleagues, I don't have the necessity of uploading it to PyPI. Is there any mechanism by which I could send them some zipped files that could create the same as pip install myproject would do? If so, should I have these in my repository?

Comment: The duplicate answer has the gist of it - the more modern wheel builder is https://pypi.org/project/build/ :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the hint! :)